# Recreating Apple Music UINavigationController title arrow

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to create the look from the "New" tab in Apple new music app:

[image]

At first, I thought the arrow is just a unicode character, but the closest symbol I have found is: ﹀, and this isn't aligned vertically, so this code produces the following

```
navigationItem.title = "All Genres﹀"
navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
```

[image]

Do you have any suggestions how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this by using a UIButton. Set its image to an image of the arrow, and its title to All Genres. You'd anyway want a callback when it's tapped, so a button would serve well functionally too.

Assign the button to the navigationItem's titleView.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working, using @rounak's solution. Here's the code for anyone wondering

```
let arrow = UIImage(named: "titleArrow")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)

let titleButton = UIButton(type: .System)
titleButton.addTarget(self, action: "pickGenre", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

titleButton.setTitle("All Genres", forState: .Normal)
titleButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
titleButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)

titleButton.setImage(arrow, forState: .Normal)
titleButton.sizeToFit()

titleButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -titleButton.imageView!.frame.width, 0, titleButton.imageView!.frame.width)
titleButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, titleButton.titleLabel!.frame.width + 2.5, 0, -titleButton.titleLabel!.frame.width)

navigationItem.titleView = titleButton
```

titleArrow@2x.png:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 version of the above:

```
    let arrow = UIImage(named: "titleArrow")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

    let titleButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    titleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickGenre), for: .touchUpInside)

    titleButton.setTitle("All Genres", for: .normal)
    titleButton.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    titleButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    titleButton.setImage(arrow, for: .normal)
    titleButton.sizeToFit()

    titleButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -titleButton.imageView!.frame.width, 0, titleButton.imageView!.frame.width)
    titleButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, titleButton.titleLabel!.frame.width + 2.5, 0, -titleButton.titleLabel!.frame.width)

    navigationItem.titleView = titleButton
```